# Enforce HTTPS for specific pages of a web application

Tags: http, website, https

I have a web application that works on both the HTTP and the HTTPS protocols. I want some of its pages (form pages) to work only on the HTTPS protocol.

The web application was developed on the ASP.NET MVC framework.

How do I achieve this?

---

There is a load balancer system behind the web server. The load balancer always redirects incoming request to the web server as http. If I redirect  a http request to the web server as https  system will enter infinite loop. Load balancer also keeps https certificates. So load balancer catches all request before. But as I mentioned I need to solve this problem.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Redirect the `http` URLs in question to the corresponding `https` URLs. You can do this in your web server's configuration.

Comment: You do 301 redirects on the sever or in the web.config file and can match patterns for each rule (string patterns)

Comment: Although unless a really good reason not to, push the whole site over to https